# Facebook is not identifying $ neither jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to write some custom script and trying to inject it to Facebook but unable to get jQuery functions executed, I have tried different approaches;

**1st Method:**

```
 Using $
```

but having this error

**Error:**

```
 <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","undefined"]]]>
```

then changed it to

**2nd Method:**

```
Using 'jQuery' instead of $
```

got this error

**Error:**

```
jQuery is not defined
```

**3rd MEthod:**

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

and

```
 $.noConflict();
```

**Error:**
same as above two methods

What should I do to make jQuery functions work?

Seen in some online solutions that people are suggesting to change the context from browser-console but this cannot be a solution as we cannot ask users to change context prior using the utility/extension/script.

Comment: Is the jQuery library imported before the script?

Comment: Library too cannot be imported I used  "<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> " but getting error "Unrecoverable syntax error"

Comment: How are you injecting stuff? And why?

Comment: facebook has headers attached to files that prevent the xss insertion of other scripts

Comment: @WizKid through Google extension and for marketing data collection.

Comment: Yea. That is not allowed in any way. Use the API to collect data